# Left Join a table but also keep the matched entry from the left table

Tags: sql

I am currently working with some tables which have about the layout below. We have a product table which contains the product with its english name. We also have some translation for the product, which are saved in a second table `translation`. Now for an old version I neet to get the enlish name together with all translations. So if I search for `productId = 1` I would expect a result like this:

```
ProductId | english | translation
1         | Wood    | NULL
1         | Wood    | Holz
1         | Wood    | Bois
```

The table layout looks like this:

The first table `Product`

```
ProductId |Name
1         | Wood
2         | Iron
3         | Copper
4         | Gold
```

The second table `Translation`

```
TranslationId | Name    | fk_product | fk_anguage
1             | Holz    | 1          | 1
2             | Eisen   | 2          | 1
3             | Kupfer  | 3          | 1
4             | Bois    | 1          | 2
```

Now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   ProductId, Product.Name AS english Translation.Name AS translation
FROM 
   Product
LEFT JOIN 
   Translation ON fk_product = ProductId
```

This works so far, that I get all translation but not the english name. Is it possible to retrive all three names in the different languages?

Comment: I don't understand.  The product name looks like the English name and it is in the second column.

Comment: The query I tried gives me all translations (for the example it should be two rows). So I get Holz and Bois for Wood. But I also need the english value as translation in the result table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `UNION ALL`?

```
SELECT p.ProductId, p.Name AS english t.Name AS translation
FROM Product p JOIN 
     Translation t
     ON t.fk_product = p.ProductId
UNION ALL
SELECT p.ProductId, p.Name, p.Name
FROM Product;
```